# Django ModelForm validation issue (true returned when false is expected)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm which is not working as expected. The method `is_valid()` returns True even for empty fields and moreover in the `clenead_data` I don't have the expected fields, but only a field which should not be there (since is not rendered by the form).
My scenario is something like this:

my form class:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
#         fields = ('one', 'two', 'three')
        widgets = {
            'fieldA': SelectDateWidget(),
            'fieldB': forms.HiddenInput(),
            # ...
        }

     fieldX = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                choices=(...),
                                initial=A_VALUE)
     fieldY = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                choices=(...),
                                initial=A_VALUE)
```

the form is rendered in the page as expected and submitted using POST (all the data is submitted correctly). Then in my controller i have something like:

```
self.form = MyForm(request.POST)
```

and `self.form.cleaned_data` has only one field inside (it's a field belonging to the model but unexpected in the form) before invoking `is_valid()` and after too.
I also tried to declare specific "fields" providing the tuple in the Meta class and viceversa specifying undesired ones using "exclude" with no luck.

I know, this is very vague... but could you give me some suggestions?

ps. the same approach with ModelForm works perfectly in other section of my project :P

...moreover if I open the interactive shell (`python manage.py shell`) and I try the following:

```
f = MyForm({})
f.is_valid()
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/MyPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 126, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/MyPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 117, in _get_errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/MyPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 272, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/MyPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 290, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: You indented `fieldX` and `fieldY` inside `class Meta:` Is this what you want? Should be indented inside the `Form` class.

Comment: no, bad formatting, sorry :P

Comment: You'll need to show your view, and your actual form code without bits commented out and properly indented.

Comment: the view is not the problem for sure (my views are just delegators to my controllers) ...read my updated question :)

Comment: Have you validate generate html form? Copy-paste html into an html validator to be sure all html is well formed. I see you have custom widget `SelectDateWidget`.

Comment: I just solved, thanks... read my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Fuuuuuuuuu!!!! O___O'

After 3 hours I realized that the problem was in the form's superclass! I have my own ModelForm which extends django's ModelForm in order to provide dynamic methods to render forms using Bootstrap templates (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).
So in my custom model I have a `allFieldsGroupedInDivs` method which is similar to "as_table" but use divs with specific classes to display data... and in order to provide more flexibility for complex form (where I have several fields and I want to order them in particular way) I have recently implemented a magic method (`__getattr__`) in order to render a single form field using the signature `thefieldGroupedInDivs` (where "thefield" is the name of the field to render). The problem is that Django uses that magic method in order to dynamically create the various `clean_field()` so my data was not cleaned properly! I solved simply by invoking the super implementation when the requested method is not in the form `*GroupedInDivs` :)

In conclusion: **PAY ATTENTION WHEN OVERRIDING DJANGO'S CLASSES!**